# Highstocks displays too many ticks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highstocks to display a chart.
X axis is a datetime..
This is what I get:

[image]

Did anybody ran into this?
Here's my data:

```
[  
   {  
      "data":[  
         [  
            1409846712000,
            1
         ],
         [  
            1410078016000,
            2
         ]
      ],
      "color":"#14baaa\u0000\u0000",
      "name":"Bought"
   }
]
```

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e6etcgje/

Comment: It might be clearer if you add a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: @Boaz I added a fiddle..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem**

Your data is made of two x-coordinates, `1409846712000` and `1410078016000`, which are UNIX timestamps in milliseconds, representing a time range between 2014-09-04 and 2014-09-07.

This means the maximum possible number of ticks is 231,304,000. Your current `tickInterval` setting is `200000`, so the number of ticks the chart is trying to display is 1,156 (= 231,304,000 / 200,000), which is obviously way more than it can fit in any readable manner.

**Possible solution**

Consider increasing the `tickInterval` setting to show a more reasonable number of ticks, for example `30000000`, which is the equivalent of about 8 (≈ 231,304,000 / 30,000,000) ticks.

### [See jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e6etcgje/1/)